# Search Against Series Of Fields - Solr

Tags: search, solr

Lets consider a product catalog with fields **Category, Brand, BrandAndCategory** And **default search field**.

If i search for  "dell laptops"  at first **solr** should search against Category field, if no results are found then against Brand field and then BrandAndCategory field and finally against the default search field.Right now i am making four different calls one by one to the **solr** from my **Java Code** to achieve this.It might affect the performance eventually.Is there any other way to achieve this from **solr** itself?.

Please help me on this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the [DisMaxQueryParser](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/05/23/whats-a-dismax/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If getting the best results at the top is enough and lower priority results towards the bottom of the result set are acceptable, then something like this may work for you:

```
 q=dell laptops&qf=Category^100 Brand^50 BrandAndCategory^10 Default
```

Comment: q.alt will work only if the qf field is empty or not present.